# Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP) - External script

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, amp-html

I have implemented the AMP page for Mobile a 1 year ago, I want to import the external script to generate the dynamic phone number changes(Infinity phone Number). I heard as per the AMP standards we cant import the external script into amp pages.
Is there any new version released to import the external scripts in the AMP pages? Can you please some one to help me.

Comment: See examples on the official website: https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-script/ - There is an answer to your question.

Comment: I can suggest you a work around to use load your specific element with  Amp-iframe into your amp site. You can use any css and javascript in your iframe template.

Comment: Thanks to all, Will check the details